The minimum of a quadratic form on a sphere.
I am asked to find the minima of a quadratic $\boldsymbol{w}^TC\boldsymbol{w}$ where
$C$ is real positive definite symmetric, $\boldsymbol{w}=(w_1,\cdots,w_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\|\boldsymbol{w}\|^2=k$ and $\sum w_i = 1$.
I try to solve it like this:
Suppose $\lambda_1\geqslant \lambda_2\geqslant \cdots\geqslant \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $C$.
By the condition, there is orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $C=P^TDP$, where
$D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$.
Moreover, we set $\boldsymbol{y}=P\boldsymbol{w}$. Then
\begin{align*}
    \|\boldsymbol{y}\|^2 &= \|P\boldsymbol{w}\|^2=
    \langle P\boldsymbol{w},P\boldsymbol{w} \rangle \\
    &=\boldsymbol{w}^TP^TP\boldsymbol{w}=\boldsymbol{w}^T I \boldsymbol{w} \\
    &= \sum w_i^2 = \|\boldsymbol{w}\|^2
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
    \boldsymbol{w}^T C \boldsymbol{w} &= \boldsymbol{w}^T P^T D P \boldsymbol{w} = 
    \boldsymbol{y}^T D \boldsymbol{y}\\
    &=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y_i^2   
    \geqslant \lambda_n \|\boldsymbol{y}\|^2\\
    & = \lambda_n \|w\|^2= k\lambda_n
\end{align*}
where the equality holds if and only if
$\boldsymbol{y}=(0,0,\cdots,\sqrt{k})'$. But the question is: with the constraint $\sum w_i=1$, the domain of $\boldsymbol{w}$ is not a real sphere. So can the equality really takes an equal? How can I find the minima?

The equation $w^tCw=k$ with $k>0$ defines a family of (hyper)ellipsoids wich are all homothetic images one of the other (think to the image of russian dolls).
You are looking for the smallest value of $k$ such there is in fact a contact point of one of these ellipsoids with the hyperplane with equation $\sum_k w_k =1$ ; in this contact point, write that the gradients are proportionnal (Lagrange's method) :
$$2Cw=\lambda \textbf{1}$$
where $\textbf{1}$ is the vector with all its components equal to $1$.
Otherwise said, the point of contact is
$$w=\tfrac12 \lambda C^{-1}\textbf{1}\tag{1}$$
It (apparently) remains an unknown $\lambda$. In fact, a last treatment is necessary that will be obtained by pre-multiplying (1) with $\textbf{1}^T$ giving :
$$\textbf{1}^Tw=\tfrac12 \lambda \textbf{1}^TC^{-1}\textbf{1}\tag{2}$$
knowing that the LHS of (2)$w$ is equal to $1$ because $w$ belongs to the hyperplane of vectors with the sum of their coordiantes equal to $1$.
From (2) we deduce that $$\lambda = \tfrac{2}{\textbf{1}^TC^{-1}\textbf{1}}\tag{3}$$
Plugging (3) into (1) gives :
$$w=\tfrac{C^{-1}\textbf{1}}{\textbf{1}^TC^{-1}\textbf{1}}\tag{4}$$

See here an analogous question where the asker has found the same Lagrangian method as given in my solution above, but cannot reach a conclusion 1) because $C$ isn't positive definite 2) Because he/she hasn't remembered that unknown parameter $\lambda$ can be eliminated by "remembering" that the solution must verify the given equations.

Do you mean$$
1=\boldsymbol{1}^T \boldsymbol{w} = \lambda \boldsymbol{u}^TC^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}
$$
which gives $\lambda=\dfrac{1}{\boldsymbol{1}^TC^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}}$ and
$$
\boldsymbol{w}=\dfrac{C^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}}{\boldsymbol{1}^TC^{-1}\boldsymbol{1}}
$$

@Vilhaze Right ! I have added this final step to my answer (with an intermediate $2$ that disappears in the computation...)

That's right...

Suppose that $|\boldsymbol{w}|^2=k$ for some fixed $k>0$. If we are using Lagrange multiplier, the $f$ should be $$
f(\boldsymbol{w},\lambda_1,\lambda_2)= \boldsymbol{w}^TC\boldsymbol{w}-\lambda_1(\boldsymbol{1}^T\boldsymbol{w}-1)-\lambda_2(\boldsymbol{w}^T\boldsymbol{w}-k)
$$
so that (ignore the $2$ in gradient)
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \boldsymbol{w}}=
\boldsymbol{w}^TC-\lambda_1 \boldsymbol{1}^T-\lambda_2\boldsymbol{w}^T=0
$$
which gives
$$
\boldsymbol{w}^T(C-\lambda_2 I)=\lambda_1\boldsymbol{1}^T
$$

Take transpose and use $C-\lambda_2 I$ is also symmetric to get
$$
(C-\lambda_2 I)\boldsymbol{w}=\lambda_1\boldsymbol{1} \quad(1)
$$
I think the $\lambda_1\boldsymbol{1}$ is the effect of $\sum w_i = 1$ (Otherwise, $(C-\lambda_2 I)=\boldsymbol{0}$ which means $\lambda_2$ is the eigenvalue).
Then should I solve (1) to get $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

From  $\boldsymbol{w}^TC=\lambda_1 \boldsymbol{1}^T+\lambda_2\boldsymbol{w}^T \ \tag{1}$ 1) post-multiplication of (1) by $\boldsymbol{w}$, we get : $$\boldsymbol{w}^TC\boldsymbol{w}=\lambda_1 1+\lambda_2 k \tag{2}$$ 2) whereas postmultiplication of (1) by $\boldsymbol{1}$, we get  $$\boldsymbol{w}^TC\boldsymbol{1}=n \lambda_1 1+\lambda_2 \tag{3}$$Equations (2)+(3) constitute a (numerical) linear system easy to solve.
